# Преобразование строки в число

Tags: c++

Имеется строка, представляющая собой 16ричное число CString devAddress="А00761ADEFA6" (полученная из адреса устройства удалением ":" между разрядами).

Как проще всего преобразовать ее в числовое значение? Желательно с помощью стандартной функции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int n;
sscanf(devAddress, "%x", &n);
```

*Следите, чтобы не переполнилось!*

Для 64-битных адресов:

```
long long n;
sscanf(devAddress, "%llx", &n);
```

Comment: значения int явно не хватит для хранения значения адреса, тк максимальное значение будет FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF = 2^48-1 если я не ошибся

Comment: @Евген хм… у нас, вроде как, разрядность int совпадается с разрядностью процессора, а, значит, и с разрядностью адреса? Ну если там какие-то такие особенности, хм… ну ща подправлю ответ…

Comment: А в примере, и правда, 12 цифр — стало быть, 6 байтов… забавно.

Answer (score 2):

strtol - там целое семейство функций. различные числовые базы. базовая функция для ваших нужд. по сути atoi - это обертка над ней.

http://opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=strtol&category=3&russian=0